# Regarding a sentence involving coordination and subject-auxiliary inversion

Tags: syntactic-analysis, subject-verb-inversion, ellipses, coordinating-conjunctions

When I am reading a paper, I come across a long sentence:

> Only when this pain remains with you, is with you eternally, can you enjoy eternally the pace and dance of humanity, can praise the shouts and songs of life, take happiness from suffering, create meaning in nothingness.

If I mistake not, this sentence can be broken up into the following six propositions:

> (1)This pain remains with you.

> (2)This pain is with you eternally.

> (3)You can enjoy eternally the pace and dance of humanity.

> (4)You can praise the shouts and songs of life.

> (5)You can take happiness from suffering.

> (6)You can create meaning in nothingness.

Apparently, the long sentence is equivalent to

> Only when both (1) and (2) are true, all of (3), (4), (5) and (6) are true.

Consequently, the original sentence makes heavy use of both coordination and inversion, which looks rather artificial. In addition, is it permissible to insert commas between verbal phrases? Is it grammatical to leave out the pronoun (namely *you*) and the modal verb (namely *can*)?

Do I correctly understand the sentence?

Comment: There are a lot of existing questions about ellipsis which cover similar sentences. Although it's odd to have "can" before "praise" but not before the later verbs. I'm not sure what you mean by *artificial*, are you expecting an answer to that? It's not something your mate would say down the pub; it's literary writing; but questions about literary techniques are probably better asked elsewhere.

Comment: Your understanding is the same as mine. An abstract is available at *Shi Tiesheng and the Nature of the Human.* https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/0148333118789171?icid=int.sj-abstract.similar-articles.2 This style of florid prose is all too common among those promoting some sort of mystic belief system or spiritual philosophy for life. It is very much a sociolect. And I would agree that it is artificial, as opposed to natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, but there is one typo in the sentence:

> Only when this pain remains with you, is with you eternally, can you enjoy eternally the pace and dance of humanity, can **you** praise the shouts and songs of life, take happiness from suffering, create meaning in nothingness.

This use of commas without conjunctions to join long verb phrases is nonstandard, though here it conveys more of an ornate literary style than an impression of incorrectness. It's not quite a comma splice, since these aren't fully separate independent clauses, but it's similar.

The structure may become clearer if we add conjunctions and expand the conjuncts a bit:

> Only when this pain remains with you, and only when this pain is with you eternally, can you enjoy eternally the pace and dance of humanity and can you praise the shouts and songs of life, take happiness from suffering, and create meaning in nothingness.

Comment: I would say the typo is not a missing *you* but an extraneous *can*: *...can you enjoy, praise, take, create...*

Comment: @TinfoilHat Good point; either is possible. Your way is likely more parsimonious.